# Jquery display only one of the selected option + required

Tags: jquery, html, input

Currently I have the problem that I display all options and only the selected option is needed. If nothing is selected, don't display the option, only if one of the options is selected.

The selected option should have a required field. Because both are required it is not possible to submit.

Thank you for your explanation, advice and support.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#problem').on('change', function(){
$('.display, .display_1').show();


if (this.value.trim()) {
   if (this.value !== 'test') {
   $('.display').hide();
   }

if (this.value !== 'test1') {
   $('.display_1').hide();
   }   
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="e">
<table id="tableId">
<tr> 
<td>Problem:</td>
<td><select required id="problem" name="problem">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="test">test</option>  
<option value="test1">test1 </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>


<tr class="display">
<td>Router</td>
<td><input id="router" name="router" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" required></td>
</tr>

<tr class="display_1">
<td>Switch</td>
<td><input id="switch" name="switch" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50"    required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="submit"  class="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the HTML and added some CSS as well. Basically this is a simple `if` statement that shows one or the other of the input fields depending on the value of the select statement:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#problem").on("change", function(){
        $(".input.text").hide();
        $(".input.text input").removeAttr("required");
        if(this.value === "test"){
            $(".input.text#router").show();
            $(".input.text#router input").prop("required", true);
        }else if(this.value === "test1"){
            $(".input.text#switch").show();
            $(".input.text#switch input").prop("required", true);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
form .input{
   display: flex;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form .input input, form .input select{
   margin-left: 20px;
}

form .input.text{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="e">
    <div class="input">
        <span>Problem:</span>
        <select required id="problem" name="problem">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="test">test</option>  
            <option value="test1">test1 </option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input text" id="router">
        <span>Router</span>
        <input id="router" name="router" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50">
    </div>
    <div class="input text" id="switch">
        <span>Switch</span>
        <input id="switch" name="switch" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50">
    </div>
    <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi symlink thank you so much! but i have a problem by submitting the value, because both are required, only the selected option should be required. how to solve this issue? any idea?

Comment: symlink is this also possible with tr and td  instead of div? i tried but is not working, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @James Yes, you might have to alter your jQuery, though. Read up on selecting DOM elements with jQuery for more info

Comment: thank you, could not alter it correctly. Do you have an example? thank you for your support